Not able to connect to DB2 database via .net code
I am working on a web application migration project to dotnet where i need rewrite the DB2 connection in the new code. I am not able to connect to DB2 database via .net code whereas i am able to do a test connection via DB2 CLI on Windows machine.
Getting below error:

"ERROR [42705] [IBM] SQL1013N  The database alias name or database
name "" could not be found.  SQLSTATE=42705\r\n"

I am using below template for DB2:
String MyDb2ConnectionString = "database=alias;uid=userid;pwd=password;";            
DB2Connection MyDb2Connection = new DB2Connection(MyDb2ConnectionString);
MyDb2Connection.Open();

Can anybody please help me to connect to DB2 database ?

you are missing the server https://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2/

yes That works. thanks for pointing out the missing parameter
